# How to limit choices on dropdown box for edit form?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I have an edit form with a dropdown status box and I would like to limit the options to just two of the five. Can that be done? Maybe with JQuery?

Comment: Hi @Mike are you need to do that for the only edit form or also new form ? or also for new ? also, what's the type of this column is it a choice field or lookup field ? also, what's the type of your form is it infopath form or default edit form ?

Comment: MY hero M.Qassas :)  For the Edit Form only and it is a regular choice dropdown box on a regular SharePoint form ( 2010 ).  Thank you!

Comment: It looks doable using jQuery. Did you face any issues when trying same with jQuery?

Comment: JQuery works but I don't know code per se unfortunately.

Comment: This has been  classic since jQuery became popular in 2007. Pick any answer to start with: https://www.google.nl/search?q=limit+checkbox+jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this for all other 3 option which you dont want in

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
  {            
    $("select[title='YourDropdownTitle'] option[value='foo1']").remove();
    $("select[title='YourDropdownTitle'] option[value='foo2']").remove();
    $("select[title='YourDropdownTitle'] option[value='foo3']").remove();
   }
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong? This won't work. I placed it an CEWP: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script><script>
 $(document).ready(function ()
  {            
    $("select[title='status'] option[value='Open']").remove();
    $("select[title='status'] option[value='Approved by HP1']").remove();
    $("select[title='status'] option[value='Hold]").remove();
   } 
    });

    </script>

Comment: just upload the jquery file in document library and reference it from there. dont use CDN url directly